# Numpy loadtxt encoding

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, ubuntu-12.04, cp1252

I am trying to load data with numpy.loadtxt. The file I'm trying to read is using cp1252 coding. Is there a possibility to change the encoding to cp1252 with numpy?

The following

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
myfile = '/path/to/myfile'
mydata = np.loadtxt(myfile, skiprows = n)
```

gives:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 189: invalid start byte

The file contains metadata (first n rows) followed by a table of floats.

This problem only occurs when running this on Ubuntu (12.04). On Windows it works well. For this reason I think this problem is related to the encoding.

Opening the file as shown in the following works well, too:

```
import codecs
data = codecs.open(myfile, encoding='cp1252')
datalines = data.readlines()
```

However I'd like to use `np.loadtext` to directly read the data into a numpy array.

Comment: `ox6f` in cp1252 is `ö`, what does your input look like?

Comment: as far as you use `numpy 1.8.1` and `n` is correct. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to open the file with the appropriate encoding before reading it with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import codecs

n=10

filecp = codecs.open(myfile, encoding = 'cp1252')
mydata = np.loadtxt(filecp, skiprows = n)
```

Comment: I have the hunch that this leads to a file descriptor leak unless one uses a context manager (`with`).