# Python numpy's loadtxt and windows pathing?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use numpy's loadtxt command, so I tried this:

```
lines = loadtxt("D:/My Desktop/Enwate syllables.txt", comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=False)
```

but that fails hard with "could not convert string to float: b'\xef\xbb\xbfen'"

I did try

```
f = open("D:/My Desktop/Enwate syllables.txt")
```

and that works fine. What am I doing wrong with loadtxt?

PS. It's not an encoding issue since as shown above the "open" command works on it perfectly well, I get the text lines and everything. And by the way, the file is a simple ascii text file with one word on each line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy loadtxt encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694736/numpy-loadtxt-encoding)

Comment: It would help if you gave us a sample of this file.  Is '\xef\xbb\xbfen' actually one of those simple ascii words?

Comment: At this point, perhaps I should delete this question, as I stopped using loadtxt and went back to using a simple open, which did what I needed it to do.

Comment: the issue is what I mentioned in the answer ,did it not help

Comment: I am going to assume it does fix the issue, since I wound up going a different route - thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention the dtype before hand ,so that numpy can allocate it 
for example

```
from io import StringIO 
j= StringIO(u'c 1\nd 2')
np.loadtxt(j)
```

fails with `ValueError: could not convert string to float: c`

but

```
np.loadtxt(j,dtype={'names': ('char', 'num'),'formats': ('S1', 'i4')})
```

works perfectly fine .

so if your text file has both of  numeric data type and character data type ,you need to mention its format using the `dtype`

P.S -if you try a file with only numeric values  `loadtxt` will not fail ,so I guess its primary data type is float ,if your file have strings ,then you need to use `dtype` as per your fields type